# Batch file for/do cycle \Overlook was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I'm made this simple batch script that reads devices line by line from Device_List file and for each device delete some folders using Windows samba shared folder.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\Device_List.txt) do (
set computer=%%a
SET path=\\%computer%\c$\Dir_to_delete
DEL %path%\* /s /f /q
)
```

If I run program I take ***\Overlook was unexpected at this tim***e error.
Issue seems related to for cycle, since if I remove it, other commands works as expected.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and don't mess with the `%path%` variable. It tells Windows where to find its executables. Choose another variable name.

Comment: Thank you very much I've solved thanks your suggestions. Thank you again